# Как в Postgres (PostGIS) degrees конвертировать в meters

Tags: sql, postgresql, координаты, postgis

Существует таблица с таким DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    build_number DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    location GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)
);
```

В таблице 100 записей, каждое поле location имеет значение:

```
sprintf('SRID=4326;POINT(%s %s)', $faker->longitude(55, 55.08), $faker->latitude(82.93, 83.01))
```

То есть точки сосредоточены в одном месте не далеко от друг друга.

Теперь отображение точека на карте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Левая карта, это вывод всех точек. Права карта имеет вывод красной точки в радиусе которой будет происходить поиск.
Красная точка находится в координате `55.0502, 82.9615`

Производим поиск с радиусом 500м. Запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM "buildings"
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(55.0502 82.9615)'), 500, TRUE)
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Производим поиск с радиусом 1500м. Запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM "buildings"
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(55.0502 82.9615)'), 1500, TRUE)
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат на обеих картах в уменьшеном маштабе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ПРОБЛЕМА 1:**
Если location является GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326) т.е. как в выше указаном DDL, то ссылаясь на документацию функции видно, что 3й аргумент будет в метрах

```
boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters);

boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters, boolean use_spheroid);
```

Результат виден в выше находящимся описание. Как с 4 агрументом, так и без него.

---

**ПРОБЛЕМА 2**
Если поле location создать как GEOMETRY(POINT,4326), то выборки происходят правильные, но с 3й агрумент требует конвертации. Как конвертировать degrees в meters?